# Is there a way for HTML form to submit default value?

Tags: html, forms

Is there a way (without JS) to make input fields POST a default value in case some input fields were blank when the submit was executed?

In other words: I want to avoid on server side reciving stuff like

> "ID=&PW="

```
<form>
    <input name="ID" value="stuff"/>
    <input name="PW" value="stuff"/>
</form>
```

setting the value doesn't really help as the user still can clean the input field by him self.

Comment: What about enforcing the default server-side?

Comment: I don't like that one. Because I'm working with C and would liek to use the fucntion `strtok()` but when I had to detect the defualt server side that wouldn't work and I had to restructure my current code. So if there is a HTML way to solve this, I would love to use it. otherwise I HAVE to do it on server side :/

Comment: Whats the -1 for? I love people rage downvoting?

Comment: Not commenting in regards to the -1 since it wasn't me, but I am curious why in this age anybody would use C for processing html forms?

Comment: @McAden because of some personal reasons. But this doesn't belpong here I guess ;)

Comment: a fair enough answer, GL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do so in pure HTML. Even if you use JS to setup defaults, someone can intercept and modify HTTP Request.

Never trust input values. You can't assume their values.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not without JavaScript.
...but it would be so easy with JavaScript. Not that I advocate inline scripts, but how about:

```
<input name="ID" value="stuff" onBlur="this.value=this.value==''
         ? 'default' 
         : this.value;" />
```

The Javascript you see is a simple ternary operator, following the pattern:

```
myVar = condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

So it's checking if the input is blank. If so, set it to a default; if not, let it be.

Comment: Uhm what syntax is this? As I already mentioned in a comment, I'm not working with PHP, I'm working with plain C, using FCGI ;)

Comment: It's Javascript, with some line-breaks for easier reading. See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/yHj7Q/

Comment: Ah ok, but I want my webpage to also run in non JS supporting browsers ;)Thanks for your effort, but for me this doesn't help. But +1 as this may be helpfull for others :)

Comment: Understood. That's why my short answer was no.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply enforce the default value server-side. Otherwise the user will always have the ability to trip you up. You can use javascript to reduce the chance of this happening but javascript will always be exposed to the user. Html doesn't have a method for this and even if I'm wrong and it does, or does in the future - such a thing is ALSO exposed to the user.

You're talking about using `strtok`. I'd recommend simply breaking the tokenizing out twice. Once for the `&`, and then within each of those results again for the `=` (obviously if the second result of each pair is blank or null, substituting the default). Otherwise, tokenize it yourself, still on the server.

Comment: Ty for this hint, its a nice idea. Thanks. I would have been now going to wirte my own strtok fucntion to fit my needs. but tokenize twice and split in the token for the `=` is a much better idea than mine would have been! realy thanks!:)